# Showing and hiding groups of markers with Mapbox/LeafletJS

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I'm using MapboxJS to build a map.

I currently give it a geoJson object of all my markers, which show up with no problem.

As each point has a category, I'd like to add a control layer with checkboxes for each category, so users can show/hide each category.

I've tried loading each marker individually into a layer but I'm getting mapbox errors.

How should I approach this?

Thanks in advance.

Mei

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I managed to write something myself.

I created a global variable to hold the categories I wanted to use, and added a category property to the geoJson object. I also had a global for all the markers.

I then used L.control to add a div, wnd looped through the categories to create checkboxes.

I added an event listener to those inputs, which looped through each marker and either added or removed them from the map (each marker is a layer), depending on what was the checkbox's value.

Details are on the blogpost http://meigwilym.com/custom-marker-controls-with-mapbox-and-leafletjs/

I don't know if this is the best method, but it's the only thing I can get working.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't played with mapbox, but with leafletjs, most of what you need is in http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control.html

The code from that page is as follows:

```
var littleton = L.marker([39.61, -105.02]).bindPopup('This is Littleton, CO.'),
denver    = L.marker([39.74, -104.99]).bindPopup('This is Denver, CO.'),
aurora    = L.marker([39.73, -104.8]).bindPopup('This is Aurora, CO.'),
golden    = L.marker([39.77, -105.23]).bindPopup('This is Golden, CO.');

var cities = L.layerGroup([littleton, denver, aurora, golden]);

var grayscale = L.tileLayer(mapboxUrl, {id: 'MapID', attribution: mapboxAttribution}),
streets   = L.tileLayer(mapboxUrl, {id: 'MapID', attribution: mapboxAttribution});

var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [39.73, -104.99],
    zoom: 10,
    layers: [grayscale, cities]
});

var baseMaps = {
"Grayscale": grayscale,
"Streets": streets
};

var overlayMaps = {
"Cities": cities
};

L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);
```

Based on that code, all you'd need to change is to have multiple elements added to the `overlayMaps` variable, each with a set of markers.

So you could have:

```
var myMarkers = L.layerGroup([
    L.marker([39.75,-105.1]),
    L.marker([39.76,-105.3])
]);
```

and then you'd modify the definition of overlayMaps in the above code like so:

```
var overlayMaps = {
    "Cities": cities,
    "My Markers": myMarkers
};
```